# /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Tags: bash

What is wrong with this script?!

```
define erase_containers
    @for container_name in ${CONTAINER_NAMES};\
        do\
            if [[ $$(docker ps --filter "name=^/$$container_name$$" --format '{{.Names}}') == $$container_name ]];\
                then\
                    docker stop $$container_name;\
            fi;\
            if [[ 1 == 1 ]];\
                then\
                    echo blablabla;\
        done;
endef
```

This is the function that is supposed to be called in a Makefile. It works just fine without the second `if` clause. But if add it I get the above-mentioned error.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close the last if, so

```
.....
       if [[ 1 == 1 ]];\
                then\
                    echo blablabla;\
       fi;\       
      done;
.....
```

Comment: oh yeah, that's just another bug, sorry. But still it yields `/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: editet the "fi", try to put only this if in the file that worked before, 
or just verify if all your if, for, or any other functions are closed correctly;